# Enabling button of one form another forms button click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I have form1 and form2 running at the same time .

The flow is as below

```
1) Click form1 button
2) disable form1 button
3) show form2 ( form 1 is not closed)
4) click form 2 button 
5) close form 2
6) enable form1 button
```

I have done till 5th step . Couldn't do 6th . Can anyone help ?

Comment: What problem did you encounter that prevented you from doing step 6?

Comment: I instantiated new form1 . I think thats not the way to follow when form 1 is already running . Wat else need to be done ?

Comment: Do you really need these forms running "at the same time", or is form2 a subform of form1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - creating another copy of `Form1` is not the right way to go.

It's not very clear from your question, but it sounds like you want to re-enable the same button that you disabled before opening Form2. In that case, you can listen to `Form2`'s [`FormClosed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event and handle it in `Form1`:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public void ShowForm2()
    {
        myButton.Enabled = false;
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.FormClosed += HandleForm2Closed;
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void HandleForm2Closed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: even though @Anthony Pegram's solutions solves my prob . This is best one to follow i feel

Comment: I agree, and my lack of winform development might be shining through. Duh, events.